# Errors aplenty installing Topojson -- contextify? node-gyp rebuild? Other threads not working Lion 10.7.5

Tags: macos, node.js, topojson

UPDATE: SOLVED like this:

1.Like @salem said, I had to install contextify:

```
npm install contextify
```

1. then `sudo npm install -g topojson` threw an error about needing to accept an Xcode license agreement. It threw the command I needed too, so I ran that, then tried s`udo npm install -g topojson` again, and it worked!

---

Problem:

So, I'm getting errors aplenty with:

sudo npm install -g topojson

I haven't found solution in other threads.

1. Is Xcode right? I have Xcode 4.6.2 -- and update gives this error: "Xcode [5] can’t be installed on “Macintosh HD” because Mac OS X version 10.8.4 or later is required."
2. node & npm seem ok … they both spit out some help at node --help and npm --help
   2a.  I've tried deleting then reinstalling node using node-v0.10.24-darwin-x86.tar.  Though I'm very unclear on what any of this is.

This is the end of the log:

```
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "topojson"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/maggielee/Downloads
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/maggielee/Downloads/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

The whole log is here: http://greencracker.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/error.txt

What do you think?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `npm install contextify`? This is a module that needs to be compiled, so you may be missing some library...

Comment: Thank you, installing contextify did it. I updated above.